# Не понимаю как убрать горизонтальный скролл, не используя при этом overflow: hidden? Новичок в вёрстке и фронте в целом

Tags: html, css, frontend

Не понимаю как убрать горизонтальный скролл, не используя при этом overflow: hidden.
Почему вообще здесь появляется скролл?
Вот сам код HTML и CSS соответственно:

```css
/* Обнуляющие стили */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :focus,
 :active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/* Обнуляющие стили */

body {
  margin: 8px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {}

.content {}

.four-block {}

.four-block__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.four-block__element {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 24%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  .four-block__element {
    width: 49%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .four-block__element {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <title>ADAPRTIVERR</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="four-block">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="four-block__row">
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 1.</div>
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 2.</div>
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 3.</div>
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 4.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: body width 100% + margin = больше чем 100%, вот и не влезает по горизонтали

Answer (score 0):

Не использовать `margin` на body в данном случае. `margin` добавляет отступ снаружи относительно самого блока, а не внутри, как Вы бы хотели. Это частая ошибка понимания `margin` в отличии от `padding`.

```css
/* Обнуляющие стили */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :focus,
 :active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/* Обнуляющие стили */

body {
  padding: 8px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {}

.content {}

.four-block {}

.four-block__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.four-block__element {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 24%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  .four-block__element {
    width: 49%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .four-block__element {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <title>ADAPRTIVERR</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="four-block">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="four-block__row">
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 1.</div>
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 2.</div>
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 3.</div>
            <div class="four-block__element">Блок 4.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```